# Saving the weights of a single neural network in a tensorflow graph

Tags: tensorflow

How does one save the weights of a single neural network in a tensorflow graph so that it can be loaded in a different program into a network with the same architecture?

My training code requires 3 other neural networks for the training process alone. If I were to use `saver.save(sess, 'my-model)'`, wouldn't it save all the variables in the tensorflow graph? This doesn't seem correct for my use case.

Maybe this comes from my misunderstanding of how tensorflow should work. Am I approaching this problem correctly?

Comment: You can choose which variable you want to save (https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model). Just write: saver = tf.train.Saver({"my_var": my_var})

Answer (score 2):

The best approach would be to use tensorflow variables scope. Say you have model_1, model_2, and model_3 and you only want to save model_1:

First, define the models in your training code:

```
with tf.variable_scope('model_1'):
    model one declaration here
    ...
with tf.variable_scope('model_2'):
    model one declaration here
    ...
with tf.variable_scope('model_3'):
    model one declaration here
    ...
```

Next, define saver over the variables of model_1:

```
model_1_variables = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope="model_1")
saver = tf.train.Saver(model_1_variables)
```

While training you can save a checkpoint just like you mentioned:

```
saver.save(sess, 'my-model')
```

After your training is done and you want to restore the weights in your evaluation code, make sure you define model_1 and saver the same way:

```
with tf.variable_scope('model_1'):
    model one declaration here
    ...
model_1_variables = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope="model_1")
saver = tf.train.Saver(model_1_variables)
sess = tf.Session()
saver.restore(sess, 'my-model')`
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks.